# How to exclude file extensions in the output filelist.txt, within a batch "dir" script in CMD

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, pdf

I am a CMD newbie and have a question with a batch script I am working on.
I have a parent directory with 30 sub-directories containing .pdf files, and I need a filelist.txt for each sub-directory, and have each filelist.txt save as the file name of the sub-directory it belongs too. This has been completed with the script below:

```
     @echo off
     cd /d "C:\Desktop\parentDir"
            for /d %%a in (*) do ( 
            DIR /B /ON /A-D "%%a" > %%a.txt.  
            move %%a.txt "%%a" >nul 
        )
```

My question is how, can I remove file extensions in the output of each filelist.txt. For ex. when I run the script now, the output .txt file shows 1111.pdf
1112.pdf
I need the ".pdf" removed

I know with a "for" command you can "do" echo %%~na to remove file extensions, but I have no clue how/where to factor this into the current script.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `DIR` command to list all files. It does not have a switch to hide extension.

You can replace the `DIR` command with a `FOR loop`, like you pointed out.

```
cd /d "C:\Desktop\parentDir"
    for /d %%a in (*) do ( 
    for %%f in ("%%a\*") do @echo %%~nf >> %%a.txt.
    move %%a.txt "%%a" >nul 
)
```

Comment: Xavero: Genius! Cant thank you enough, works perfectly!